Why is my 3D data volume rendering partially black?
Code to render the 3D data body:
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1),size=(1024,1024))  

src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(values)
vol=mlab.pipeline.volume(src)

seismic = np.loadtxt('bwr.txt')
color = seismic
from tvtk.util.ctf import ColorTransferFunction
ctf = ColorTransferFunction()
vol._volume_property.set_color(ctf)
cv = np.linspace(-280000,280000,len(color))
for i in range(len(color)):
    ctf.add_rgb_point(cv[i], color[i,0], color[i,1], color[i,2])
vol._ctf = ctf
vol.update_ctf = True

# mlab.axes(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z')
# mlab.colorbar()
# mlab.outline()

mlab.show()

The resulting image:

The color is supposed to be blue, white and red. Why does it show a lot of black and how do I modify the code to get rid of the black?
